# ¿Porque los códigos en PHP salen comentados?

Tags: php, html

Hola a todos los colegas: hace poco he empezado con html y php combinandolos por unos 2 meses todo andaba bien, pero ahora el navegador(MOZILLA FIREFOX, el cual establecí como predeterminado) identa todo código que sea PHP(inclusive si esta en un "archivo.php").
No probé con otros navegadores pero sí en otras máquinas y el código funciona a la perfección.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el problema está que abris el archivo script.php directamente no lo abris con un servidor por ejemplo apache para que ejecute los script de php

Answer (score 0):

Estas abriendo el archivo Php usando el protocolo file. Eso significa que lo estas usando directamente. 
Php está diseñado para correr en un servidor Web como apache o IIS.

Puedes usar esta instalación WAMP= windows+apache+mysql+php. 
http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Es fácil de los instalar y estas listo para trabajar